# Best way to parse non-uniform JSON in python (Nested/Non Nested)

Tags: python

I'm querying an API and would like to store the results of that API, the JSON response looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "id": 123456, 
    "geo": {
        "region": {
            "city": false
        },
        "country": "United States",
        "ethnicity": "White",
      }
}
```

The dictionary I'm trying to parse it into looks like this:

```
dictP = {
        "name": "",
        "id": 0,
        "geo.region.city": "",
        "geo.country": "",
        "geo.ethnicity": ""
}
```

There's a lot more data, about 120 data points being returned, lots of nested/non nested; so I'm excluding a big chunk of data thats useless to me. Only extracting what i need. The issue is sometimes the data is missing, IE:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "id": 123456, 
    "geo": {
        "region": null,
        "country": "United States",
        "ethnicity": "White",
      }
}
```

and:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "id": 123456, 
    "geo": null
}
```

or:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith", 
    "id": null, 
    "geo": null
}
```

What's the best way to parse this? I have about 75 data points i want to parse, writing if/else statements or try/except statements 75 times does not make sense. The data needs to all be uniform because I'm saving to CSV, so ultimately I'd like to fill "None" for missing data, i can't seem to find a library that does this. Advice appreciated.

Comment: How do you parse it? This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704478/how-to-handle-missing-keys-in-list-of-json-objects-in-python

Comment: @Asdoost Im not sure how to use json.get() on nested keys, im also not sure how to pass the key values ie: test.something as a value to look for in a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle missing keys in list of JSON objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704478/how-to-handle-missing-keys-in-list-of-json-objects-in-python)

Comment: @Asdoost Nope, sadly it doesn't

Comment: Copy a piece of json file and what you want to get. People will help you.

Answer (score 2):

How about [FlatDict](https://flatdict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?.

```py
import json
from flatdict import FlatDict

response_as_json = json.loads(response_as_text)  # convert into python dictionary
result = dict(FlatDict(response_as_json, delimiter='.'))
```

Above output a python dictionary looks like this:

```py
{'geo.country': 'United States',
 'geo.ethnicity': 'White',
 'geo.region': None,
 'id': 123456,
 'name': 'John Smith'}
```

### EDIT:

I forgot the part about CSV.
Once you have flat dictionaries, you can just put them into pandas.

```py
>>> d1
{'name': 'John Smith', 'id': 123456, 'geo.region.city': False, 'geo.country': 'United States', 'geo.ethnicity': 'White'}
>>> d2
{'name': 'John Smith', 'id': 123456, 'geo.region': None, 'geo.country': 'United States', 'geo.ethnicity': 'White'}

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> list_of_dict = [d1, d2]  # Put as many as you want in this list.
>>> table = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
>>> table
         name      id geo.region.city    geo.country geo.ethnicity  geo.region
0  John Smith  123456           False  United States         White         NaN
1  John Smith  123456             NaN  United States         White         NaN

>>> table.to_csv(path_to_csv)
```

Comment: Amazing! Love this library already! Any idea how i can go about idiomatically filling missing keys?

Actually! I think i can use this library, and pass the two dicts two a function, for loop, if error just replace with non!

Comment: I forgot the CSV part. I think pandas can handle that. I just edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: pandas will look up the intersection of the keys, but if there are any missing keys in the output table, you can fill with `table['missing_key'] = None`.